# How to revoke application permissions using Box API 2.0

Tags: authentication, box-api

I'm ok granting permissions to an app using Box API 2.0. But I'm in the need to let users revoke given permissions.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

To do this programmatically, you can use the [v1 logout method](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923939/ApiFunction_logout). The user can also revoke the access of any application at any time within their account settings on box.com.

Comment: sean, i am not seeing a list of approved apps in my account settings, under apps.  i know i have at least one, which was not installed through the marketplace...  i have a personal account.  does being able to revoke an app depend on account type?  or app type (marketplace or not)?

Comment: @seanrose: i was hoping to do that using Box API 2.0 as my original question. thanks for your help.